# DoCmd.TransferDatabase issues

Tags: vba, ms-access

In my code I'm creating a new database and then using DoCmd.TransferDatabase to copy some tables into it.  This used to work with no issues, now I'm getting the error: "Run-time error '3709': The search key was not found in any record.  My code is:

```
Set db = DBEngine.CreateDatabase(sPath, dbLangGeneral)
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "Microsoft Access", sPath, acTable, 
"MATerials", "MAT", False

DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "Microsoft Access", sPath, acTable, 
"new_2Kilo", "TWOK", False

DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "Microsoft Access", sPath, acTable, 
"tblCSMP", "tblCSMP", False

DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "Microsoft Access", sPath, acTable, 
"tblICMP", "tblICMP", False

DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "Microsoft Access", sPath, acTable, 
"tblMARMC_USERS", "tblMARMC_USERS", False

DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "Microsoft Access", sPath, acTable, 
"tblVisit_Personnel", "tblVisit_Personnel", False

DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "Microsoft Access", sPath, acTable, 
"Training", "Training", False

DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "Microsoft Access", sPath, acTable, 
"tblTeamMember", "tblTeamMember", False

DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "Microsoft Access", sPath, acTable, 
"WORK_NOTIFICATIONS", "WORK_NOTIFICATIONS", False
```

If I open the newly created database and click the "Enable Content" button the function will continue.  Any ideas how to work around this?

Comment: Erik, thanks but none of that seems to have worked.  It's like the newly created database is not "Trusted", so it doesn't allow me to export into it until I "Trust" it.  Is there any work around on this?

Comment: Oh, you can't export to untrusted sources using that. Either trust the database, trust the database location, or use a query to export.

Comment: How would I go about writing a query to export?  Wouldn't I still have to open the newly created database?

Comment: Erik, I figured it out and THANK YOU, it worked!

Comment: I hope it was similar to my answer which I posted at the same time

Answer (score 1):

Untrusted locations can't be exported to using `DoCmd.TransferDatabase`.

Afaik however, you can export to them just fine using queries, as these are processed on the database engine level, not the application level, and trust issues are at the application level.

To write a query that exports a table:

```
SELECT * INTO [;DATABASE=C:\Path\To\File.accdb].NewTableName FROM OldTableName
```

Note that this only exports data and not related information (indexes, which columns are visible, lookups, etc) and thus is functionally different.